# Passing JSON, deserialization failed because of backslashs

Tags: c#, json, json.net, backslash, json-deserialization

Trying to pass this object between two modules:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

Serialization:

```
transaction.ErrorMessage = "temptemptemp";
transaction.ErrorCode = 123;
transaction.ID = "0";
return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transaction));
```

Deserialization:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string json = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    Transaction transaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Transaction>(json);
}
```

in the debug window, I see the two strings like this:

- after serialization - {"ID":"0","ErrorMessage":"temptemptemp","ErrorCode":123}
- before deserialization - "{\"ID\":\"0\",\"ErrorMessage\":\"temptemptemp\",\"ErrorCode\":123}"

and so I'm getting the following exception:

> Error converting value "{"ID":"0","ErrorMessage":"temptemptemp","ErrorCode":123}" to type 'WebService.Transaction'. Path '', line 1, position 75.

Comment: What does the `Ok()` method do?

Comment: The `Ok()` function returns a `System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`

Comment: Those slashes are just escape characters, this shouldnt effect the conversion to JSON

Comment: Are you sure it's the same Transaction class?

Comment: I would recommend using async/await with webclient as  Tasks<T> are good  for  non cpu intensive work and will help scale your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are double-serializing your `transaction` object.  First you serialize it to a JSON string by manually calling

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transaction);
```

Then you pass it to [`Ok<T>(T content)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Ok%60%601%28%60%600%29) which *also* serializes its incoming value:

```
return Ok(jsonString);
```

Since the incoming value is a string, `Ok()` escapes it as a required by the [JSON standard](http://json.org/) for representation of a string literal.

Instead, let asp.net serialize it for you:

```
return Ok(transaction);
```

If you want to force JSON to be returned, you can use [`Json<T>(T content)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.json%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Json%60%601%28%60%600%29):

```
return Json(transaction);
```

Comment: I had no idea that `Ok()` was serializing the object, thanks.